# Почему при сдвиге -1 на 1 бит мы получаем -1

Tags: c++

Почему при сдвиге -1 на 1 бит мы получаем -1, если первый бит, который отвечает за знак сдвигается и по идее должно быть положительное число

```
std::cout << (-1 >> 1);
```

Comment: Знаковый сдвиг...

Comment: можешь объяснить?

Answer (score 5):

... ибо сказано в стандарте c++20 :) —

> The value of `E1 >> E2` is `E1/2^E2`, rounded down. *[Note: `E1` is right-shifted `E2` bit positions. Right-shift on signed integral types is an arithmetic right shift, which performs sign-extension. —end note]*

Впрочем, еще в стандарте c++17 было сказано иное:

> The value of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a non-negative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1/2^E2`. *If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.*

Но в целом стандарт C++20 просто узаконил сложившуюся практику.

Comment: Если не путаю, implementation-defined было указано ещё в ANSI C 1989, совместимость с которым декларировал Страуструп.

Answer (score 3):

В архитектурах x86/amd64 существует два вида сдвига вправо: бесзнаковый и знаковый. В первом случае старшие биты после сдвига заполняются нулями. Во втором - знаковыми разрядами, т.е. нулями для положительных чисел и единицами для отрицательных (у всех отрицательных знаковых целых старший бит равен 1).

Какой вид сдвига применяется для оператора `>>` в C++? Тут всё очень просто: для бесзнаковых целых (`unsigned int`) - это бесзнаковый сдвиг, для целых со знаком (`int`), соответственно, - знаковый.

Из-за особенности машинного представления отрицательных целых в x86/amd64, у числа `-1` все биты равны единице. Следовательно, после знакового сдвига вправо старшие биты устанавливаются в единицу, и как результат, все биты получившегося числа остаются равными единице, т.е. получается всё та же `-1`.

P.S. Рекомендую почитать про представление целых чисел в т.н. *дополнительном коде*.

Comment: Другое название для беззнакового сдвига -- *логический сдвиг* (инструкции lsr, lsl), а для знакового -- *арифметический сдвиг* (инструкции asr, asl) (поскольку он дает правильный результат (кроме -1) для деления отрицательных чисел на степень двойки)

Comment: @avp да, есть такое. В x86, соответственно, это инструкции shr и sar (а вот shl и sal - синонимы для одной и той же инструкции сдвига влево).

Comment: `Ещё один занимательный факт: если у числа -2147483648 (тип int) поменять знак` Смена знака у `INT_MIN` вызывает UB.

Comment: @wololo Для архитектур intel/amd смена знака числа эквивалентна инвертированию всех его бит и добавлению единицы. UB не происходит (хотя формально и может считаться, тут я хз).

Comment: `UB не происходит` [Ладно](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42677355b8489834).

Comment: @wololo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1ffe77a718939a9. Короче, по факту мы видим, что реально `tmp` и `val` принимают одно и то же значение (я был прав) и никакого UB быть не должно! Проблема в том, что разработчики стандартов C++ иногда, видимо, курят что-то запрещённое. В общем, согласен - UB. Однако совершенно идиотское. На ассемблерном уровне результат инструкции`neg` однозначен и полностью определён.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнительном коде число -1 хранится как число со всеми установленными битами.

Для байта это 11111111b, для слова 1111111111111111b, для 4-байтного целого 11111111111111111111111111111111b и так далее.

Для одного байта: если мы сдвинем 11111111b вправо на один бит мы получим x1111111b, и старший бит нужно заполнить или 0 или 1. Если мы подставит 0, то получим 01111111b, что равно 127, то есть максимально положительно знаковое значение данной длины. Если подставим 1 - получим опять 11111111b, то есть -1.

Для двух байтов соответственно мы получим или -1 или 32767. Для четырёх - -1 или 2147483647.

Авторы языка решили, что получить -1 будет более логично.

Answer (score 0):

Биты отрицательных чисел перевернуты, поэтому при сдвиге вправо 0 становятся 1. А знаковый бит который 1 так и так не будет менятся.
В случае с -1 все биты 1 так что тут кроме -1 при сдвиге вправо -1 на 1 ничего другого и быть не может.

Но результат, вобще говоря от реализации зависит. Хотя стоит отметить, что в основном все реализации делают именно такой сдвиг.

Comment: Результат зависит скорее не от реализации, а от архитектуры процессора, под которую компилируется проект. В процах intel и amd отрицательные целые представлены в дополнительном коде - именно по-этому все биты числа `-1` равны `1`, а знаковый сдвиг происходит так, как происходит. Но в какой-нибудь другой архитектуре всё может быть иначе. Так что при компиляции под какой-нибудь специфический контроллер результат сдвига вполне может оказаться иным, кто знает...

Comment: @LShadow77 под зависимостью от реализации имеется ввиду то, как компилятор реализует свдиг следуя тому или иному стандарту.